# Cannot redeclare class symfony2

Tags: symfony

When I run the command:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities
```

I'm getting a:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Sofla\SoflaBundle\Entity\RepresentanteLegal 
in /Sofla/SoflaBundle/Entity/RepresentanteLegal.php on line 14
```

I have no clue on this. The whole project is working, and I didn't get that message before, now that is on the server, it's throwing me that message.

This is the code of the beginning of the class:

namespace Sofla\SoflaBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

```
/**
 * Sofla\SoflaBundle\Entity\RepresentanteLegal
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="representante_legal")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class RepresentanteLegal
{
```

Comment: I see messages like that when I copy and paste some entity. Sometime I forgot to rename class in pasted code. But I do not know if this is your kind of problem :-/.

Comment: Please answer your own question and mark it as answered, but in a way that may help others if they have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was was Simone Demo Gentili said, I copied and pasted some entity and forgot to rename class in pasted code.

He answered my question but since he posted a comment I couldn't pick his 'comment' as the solution.